# "username/password couple is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

Trying to sign in user using postman. I have implemented OpenIdDict authentication solution using the OAuth2 token validation middelware. However when im trying to get access, i get the following error message:

> username/password couple is invalid

I have the following test user.

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var db = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    db.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var user = new User();
    var hasher = new PasswordHasher<User>();

    db.AddRange(
        new ApplicationUser { FirstName = "Thomas", LastName = "Smith", UserName = "user@test.com", 
            Email = "user@test.com", PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(user, "Password1") },
    );
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

My setup in postman:
[image: My setup in postman]

When I debug in authorizationController, my user variable turns out to be null even though the input to the variable is correct.

```
if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);
    if (user == null){
        return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse {
            Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
            ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is it because you never actually write your use to the database? Seems like you missing a db.SaveChanges(); ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that in my code example. Code has been updated. Have also checked the tables, and it update the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your code in an async method? My guess is it's not blocking on the await, and is testing if user == null before the user lookup returns. Try adding a delay in there and see if it changes it.

Comment: This could very well be the problem, but how would I use the delay?

Comment: what method is your code in? try adding async to the method signature, i.e. private async BadRequest login() {...}